# Where to download annual data for heating and cooling degree days for US counties not one-by-one, but all at the same time

Tags: usa, weather, csv, climate, noaa

Could anybody help me find reliable source for downloading csv files of [HDD and CDD](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/units-and-calculators/degree-days.php) for all USA's counties.

For those wondering about heating and cooling days definition, you can refer to [this](https://www.weather.gov/key/climate_heat_cool#:%7E:text=If%20the%20temperature%20mean%20is,result%20is%20Heating%20Degree%20Days.&text=Because%20the%20result%20is%20below,F%20%3D%2036%20Heating%20Degree%20Days).

Comment: So https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/degree_days/weighted/daily_data/2023/ClimateDivisions.Cooling.txt is not detailed enough, right?

Comment: Not actually. I can download them one by one from [NOAA Climate at a Glance County Time Series](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/monitoring/climate-at-a-glance/county/time-series) which is painful :( , but what I am looking for is to dl them all together.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use Python or Bash to write a script that will construct the csv data for you based on these two websites:

- https://www.degreedays.net/
- https://energy-data.io/energy-tools/degree-day-calculator-free/
- https://portfoliomanager.energystar.gov/pm/degreeDaysCalculator

Alternatively, you can convert some of the html tables on these websites to csv:

- https://www.nyserda.ny.gov/About/Publications/Energy-Analysis-Reports-and-Studies/Weather-Data/Monthly-Cooling-and-Heating-Degree-Day-Data
- https://www.weatherdatadepot.com/degree-day-comparison

this can be done using https://tableconvert.com/html-to-csv.

The best resource I found are from https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/degree_days/. The data here are under text format e.g. https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/degree_days/wctycddy.txt, hence you would need to use this [website](https://onlinecsvtools.com/convert-text-to-csv) or [this](https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-to-csv) to convert them to csv.